# Flutter: kotlin could not find the required jdk tools in the java installation

Tags: java, gradle, flutter

I have some problem in flutter. When I run

```
flutter run -v
```

I got some error:

> kotlin could not find the required jdk tools in the java installation 'c:\android\openjdk' used by gradle make sure gradle is running on a jdk, not jre

Comment: Are you using Intellij ?

Comment: No i didn't using intellij

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Problem statement** = No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

**Solution**

Please set the Environment variable like below to solve the issue

Variable name : **JAVA_HOME**

Variable Value : **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202**

**Note** : If you do not have jdk then download it and make sure you make the appropriate changes in the version wherever applicable.